# How to fix "DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique"?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am facing error while calling/deploying my previous contract in new contract "SimpleStorage[] public simplestoragearray;" in line 4 of the code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 

pragma_solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory{

SimpleStorage[] public simplestoragearray;

function createsimplestoragecontract() public {
    
    SimpleStorage simplestorage = new SimpleStorage();
    simplestoragearray.push(simplestorage);

}
}
```

### Error Message:

> from solidity: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
> --> contracts/test contracts/StorageFactory.sol:8:5:   | 8 |     SimpleStorage[] public simplestoragearray;   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Can you correct the styling, add the error message and also the definition of SimpleStorage.sol, please? Nobody can answer without the proper context.

Comment: Now, Check please.

Comment: Can you provide what is in file "SimpleStorage.sol" ?

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract SimpleStoraege {
    
    uint256 fn;
         struct People{
             uint256 fn;
             string name;}
         People[] public people;
         mapping(string=>uint256) public nametonumber;
      function store(uint256 _fn)public{
        fn = _fn;}
         function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
             return fn;}
         function addperson(string memory _name, uint256 _fn)public{
             people.push(People(_fn, _name));
             nametonumber[_name] = _fn;
             }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract is probably a differente name than your file.

Change the contract name so it is same as file name it should work.

It is standart practice to name contract file same as contract.

So inside SimpleStorage.sol it should be:

```
contract SimpleStorage { ... }
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! The error is solved now.